# Semi-transparent lock screen

Tags: macos, display, imac, screen-lock

On some iMacs and MacBooks (about 2 or 3 years old) my lock screen semi-transparent on the edges.

For example how it looks on the screenshot and on the photo. The same problem on MacBook 2019 year. There is no problem with the new Apple M1 %)

Is it a hardware or software problem? Looks like an old CRT display :-D
As you can see calendar shows Jule 1 — today. So, cool down about a few hours. There are no problems while unlocked.

UPD: https://www.loom.com/share/bcece4be70e74d4a8adcf6f482c1f34f

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like screen burn. If you unlock the screen and either position the dock to the side or hide it can you still see the icons? Try some different wallpapers.  The ghost dock icons do not appear on the screenshot so it's not likely software. What is you ambient temperature of the room you are in?  Is it really hot?

Comment: If the calendar says 2 today, that rules out burn-in.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a software bug. Because other windows display normally on this position. Only desktop. My room is air-conditioned. Video https://www.loom.com/share/bcece4be70e74d4a8adcf6f482c1f34f